# Storing table values into variables with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was webscraping this table on a forum and I'm having difficulty storing the values of each row into variables.

Each row has an ID, name, rarity and type. I thought the row variable on my program was a list that can be accessed by index but turns out that it isn't since it gives me "list index out of range" error.

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

Here's the code:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Legend_of_Blue_Eyes_White_Dragon"

html = urlopen(url).read() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

title = soup.find("h2", {"class": "pi-item pi-item-spacing pi-title"})
print(title.text)

table = soup.find(id="Top_table") 
table_rows = table.find_all("tr")

for tr in table_rows:           #   for each row  
    td = tr.find_all('td')      #   find all cells
    row = [i.text for i in td]  #   row = all cells from row combined (I thought this is a list that can be accessed by index??)

    id = row[0]         #this is the ROW giving me the problem, turns out can't be accessed by index :c
    name = row[1]
    rarity = row[2]
    cardType = row[3]

    print(row)
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message. _I thought the row variable on my program was a list that can be accessed by index_ `row` is a list, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first row in table_rows is the header row. The header row does not have any td which is why the row does not have the data you want. I added a simple skip of any row that has less than 4 td elements.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Legend_of_Blue_Eyes_White_Dragon"

html = urlopen(url).read() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


title = soup.find("h2", {"class": "pi-item pi-item-spacing pi-title"})
print(title.text)

table = soup.find(id="Top_table") 
table_rows = table.find_all("tr")

for tr in table_rows:           #   for each row  
    td = tr.find_all('td')      #   find all cells
    if len(td) < 4:
        continue
    row = [i.text for i in td]  #   row = all cells from row combined (I thought this is a list that can be accessed by index??)
    id = row[0]         #this is the ROW giving me the problem, turns out can't be accessed by index :c
    name = row[1]
    rarity = row[2]
    cardType = row[3]

    print(row)
```

This returns the following

```
['LOB-EN000', '"Tri-Horned Dragon"', 'Secret Rare', 'Normal Monster']
['LOB-EN001', '"Blue-Eyes White Dragon"', 'Ultra Rare', 'Normal Monster']
['LOB-EN002', '"Hitotsu-Me Giant"', 'Common', 'Normal Monster']
['LOB-EN003', '"Flame Swordsman"', 'Super Rare', 'Fusion Monster']
['LOB-EN004', '"Skull Servant"', 'Common', 'Normal Monster']
['LOB-EN005', '"Dark Magician"', 'Ultra Rare', 'Normal Monster']
['LOB-EN006', '"Gaia The Fierce Knight"', 'Ultra Rare', 'Normal Monster']
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a faster and easier approach would be to get the HTML tables directly from pandas and then create a dataframe. Here's my version below:-

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Legend_of_Blue_Eyes_White_Dragon'
html = requests.get(url, verify=False).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-6]
print(df)
```